# Jquery - Select last tr of my table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table and in one td I have an another table.

What I am trying to do is select only the last tr from the first table (which is represented in the example below).

My table HTML:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> <!--This is the one I want to select.-->
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td>.a</td>
                    <td>.a</td>
                    <td>.a</td>
                    <td>.a</td>
                    <td>.a</td>
                    <td>.a</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I have try to use jQuery .find() and so on but I can´t select it.

Can someone give me a hand with this?

Comment: What parameter did you pass to `.find()` (and so on)?

Comment: `$('table').first().children().children().last()` or `$('table table').closest('tr')` should work given this exact html... However Niet's answer is much better - give the table an ID and select rows based on that. Just my 2 cents ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Presuming you have an ID on the first table, substituting `#example`, you can use either:

`$('#example > tbody > tr:last-child')`

or

`$('#example > tbody > tr').last()`

Comment: Won't work. Check the DOM inspector.

Comment: Yes, hence the 'Substituting any class names of the table,' - I'll make that clearer :)

Answer (score 2):

Vanilla JS to the rescue!

Assuming you can get your table somehow (maybe `getElementById` if you give it an ID) then you can do this:

```
lastRow = myTable.rows[myTable.rows.length-1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("tr:last", "table")
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need give id or class like for id="outermost-table" then try with this one else it give 2 elements.

```
 $("#outermost-table tr:last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Live Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/7/

Add table id in your html like this:

```
<table id="first">
    <tr>
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>.a</td>
        <td>.a</td>
    </tr>
    <tr> 
        <td> a</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                 <tr>
                    <td>click here </td>
                    <td>click here </td>
                    <td>click here </td>
                    <td>click here </td>
                    <td>click here </td>
                    <td>click here </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then get last row by :

```
$('#first tr:last')
```

Jquery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('#first tr:last').click(function(){
        alert('got me :)');
    })
});
```

Comment: This will select the last row of the *inner* table. Probably not what OP wants.

Comment: @xec : he wanted to get last tr of his first table. And first table last tr contains another table.so it should work for all last table tr and td click.

Comment: Try clicking the "a" in the last row of the outer table - it won't work, because the last TR selected (what `tr:last` does) is inside the inner table. http://jsfiddle.net/5Y9mG/8/